# How to have a collision reset an image to a different location and update score

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision

I would like to know what im doing wrong with my collision detection.  I'm trying to make a game where the user controls a character using a virtual joystick and tries to catch donuts that fall from the top of the screen.  The joystick works and having the donut fall works but when the two object collide the score isn't updated and the donut location isn't reset to its default location like I want it to.  I have looked at several tutorials but can't seem to find my mistake.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

struct BodyType {
static let Character: UInt32 = 1
static let Knife: UInt32 = 2
static let Donut: UInt32 = 4
}

class GameScene: SKScene,      SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var score: Int = 0
    var level: Int = 0
    var scoreLabel: SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode(text: "Score: 0")
    var BoostButton: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "boost")
    var Knife: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "knife")
    var Donut: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "donut")
    var velocityMultiplier: CGFloat = 0.15
    var BoostActive: Bool = false
    var KnifeVel: CGFloat = 3
    var KnifeX: CGFloat = 0
    var KnifeY: CGFloat = 0
    var FoodX: CGFloat = 0
    var FoodY: CGFloat = 0
    var FoodVel: CGFloat = 3



    enum NodesZPosition: CGFloat {
    case Character, joystick
    }


    var Character: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "character")


    var analogJoystick: AnalogJoystick = {
        let js = AnalogJoystick(diameter: 90, images: (UIImage(named: "substrate"), UIImage(named: "stick")))
        js.position = CGPoint(x: 480, y: 75)
        js.zPosition = NodesZPosition.joystick.rawValue
        return js
    }()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

       self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
       backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
       self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

        Character.position = CGPoint(x: 100,y: 200)
        Character.size = Donut.size
        Character.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: Character.texture!, size: Character.size)
            Character.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Character.name = "Character"
        Character.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        Character.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.Character
        Character.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.Knife | BodyType.Donut
        Character.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.Knife | BodyType.Donut
        self.addChild(Character)

        self.addChild(BoostButton)
        BoostButton.position = CGPoint(x: 75, y: 75)


        Knife.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width + 100, y: 200)
        Knife.name = "Knife"
        self.addChild(Knife)

        Donut.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: self.frame.height + 150)
        Donut.name = "Donut"
        self.addChild(Donut)


        scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 65, y: self.frame.height - 40)
        scoreLabel.fontSize = 30
        scoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.black
        self.addChild(scoreLabel)

        setupJoystick()


        let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
        border.friction = 0
        self.physicsBody = border

        }

    func setupJoystick (){
        addChild(analogJoystick)
        analogJoystick.trackingHandler = {[unowned self] data in
        self.Character.position = CGPoint(x: self.Character.position.x + (data.velocity.x * self.velocityMultiplier),y: self.Character.position.y + (data.velocity.y * self.velocityMultiplier))
        self.Character.zRotation = data.angular
        }
        }

    private func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
      var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
      var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()

        if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "Character" {
            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            secondBody = contact.bodyB
        }
        else{
            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            secondBody = contact.bodyA
        }
        if firstBody.node?.name == "Character" && secondBody.node?.name == "Donut"{
            print("collison")
            score += 20
            scoreLabel.text = "Score \(score)"
            Donut.position.y = self.frame.height + 150
            Donut.position.x = CGFloat.random(in: 100..<(self.frame.width - 100))

        }
        else if firstBody.node?.name == "Donut" && secondBody.node?.name == "Character"{
            print("collison")
            score += 20
            scoreLabel.text = "Score \(score)"
            Donut.position.y = self.frame.height + 150
            Donut.position.x = CGFloat.random(in: 100..<(self.frame.width - 100))
        }
        }

    func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {

        }

    func touchMoved(toPoint pos : CGPoint) {

        }

    func touchUp(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {

        }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            for touch in (touches ){

                let location = touch.location(in: self)
                if (BoostButton.frame.contains(location)){
                    BoostActive = true
                }
                else{
                    BoostActive = false
                }
        }
        }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        }
    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        }
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

        //  if (BoostActive == true){
       //     velocityMultiplier = velocityMultiplier * 1.5
       // }
       // else{
        //    velocityMultiplier = 0.15
        //}
        FoodY = Donut.position.y
        KnifeX = Knife.position.x

        if (Knife.position.x < (self.frame.width - 20) && Knife.position.x > 20){
            Knife.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: Knife.texture!, size: Knife.size)
            Knife.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            Knife.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
            Knife.physicsBody?.pinned = false
            Knife.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
            Knife.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
            Knife.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.Knife
            Knife.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.Character
            Knife.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.Character
        }
        else{
            Knife.physicsBody = nil
        }

        if (Donut.position.y < self.frame.height && Donut.position.y > 50){
            Donut.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: Donut.texture!, size: Donut.size)
            Donut.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            Donut.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
            Donut.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.Donut
            Donut.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.Character
            Donut.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.Character
        }
        else{
            Donut.physicsBody = nil
        }


        if (FoodY < 30){
            Donut.position.y  =  self.frame.height + 150
            Donut.position.x = CGFloat.random(in: 100..<(self.frame.width - 100))
        }
        else{
            Donut.position.y = Donut.position.y - FoodVel
        }

        if (KnifeX < 0){
            Knife.position.x = self.frame.width + 150
            Knife.position.y = CGFloat.random(in: 50..<(self.frame.height - 50))
        }
        else{
            Knife.position.x = Knife.position.x - KnifeVel
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt and welcome to SO. Try putting a `print("collision detected")` as the first line of `didBegin` to see if it's actually being called i.e. if the contact has been recognised.

Comment: Why are you creating donut's `physicsBody` in `update`? That's an odd place to do it - are you sure it's getting created? Creating a physicsBody is (I think) quite 'expensive' in CPU terms (especially using 'texture' physics bodies) so you don't really want to doing it 60 times a second.

Comment: Your donut never has a stable physics body.  You create a new one or have none every update.  This is bad.

Comment: Thanks Steve and KnightofDragon.  I am new to using swift/xcode or making programs with moving objects in general, so I still have a lot to learn.  I will look into these issue tonight, I appreciate the input

Comment: I just realized I can use the bitmask to make it so that the donut doesn't collide with the border I made.  That's why I initialized the donut and knife in the update function.  The donut and knife were colliding into the other side of the border and never entering the screen but I can set it up so that only the character collides with the border I made.